# Como decodificar string na página PHP

Tags: php

Não consigo exibir em uma tela pura de *PHP*, um `echo`

[image: Erro]

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (!isset($_GET["solicitacao"])) {
$string = "Não há uma solicitação Informada";
echo utf8_encode($string);
}elseif ($_GET["solicitacao"] == "DATAS_DISPONIVEIS") {
    $dtas_disponiveis = array("02/02/2019", "20/02/2019");  
    $myJSON = json_encode($dtas_disponiveis);
    echo $myJSON;
}else{
    echo "Deu em nada!";
}
```

Comment: Consegui!! era só tirar do echo o "utf8_encode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o seu problema está relacionado aos `2 charset's` no escopo de seu arquivo `.php`. 
Tente remover o `charset=utf-8` existente no *header* e manter o `echo utf8_encode($string);` ou tente alterar o `echo utf8_encode($string);` para `echo $string;`

Comment: Okay, era isto mesmo!! Obrigado!!!  tirei o encode!!

Comment: Marca como resposta

Comment: Fico feliz em poder esclarecer algo. Caso você ache que a resposta foi útil, vale a pena aceitá-la como [útil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) sendo assim, facilitando a vida para quem estiver com o mesmo problema. Obrigado pelo reforço, Vinicius De Jesus.